# Setting Callisto Rating Control to Readonly - Window Store App

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, callisto

In my Windows Store app I am using Callisto rating controls. Some of the rating controls I just want to show the user the rating for something, I don't want them to be able to change the rating. But for the life of me I can't find a parameter in the XAML that will let me do it.

Has anyone else managed to do this?

My current XAML code for the rating control is below.

```
<callisto:Rating Background="Transparent" x:Name="rating" Margin="-3,0,0,0" Foreground="White" ItemCount="5" Value="{Binding Rating}" />
```

Comment: There's not an `IsEnabled` you can just flag to False? If @timheuer is a contrib to that proj I'd have full faith there is..

Comment: Wow totally forgot about IsEnabled, The WP8 rating control uses ReadOnly flag, so I was looking for something along those lines, Thanks!